# How to perform CCA with block design in R

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, correspondence-analysis, vegan

***Following example and data are completely fabricated:***

Suppose I am studying grooming behaviour in apes. I have **four cages**, **8 apes in each** (4 females +  males). For 24 hours I did an observations with aim to record **the number of events when females were grooming males**.

---

[image]

---

I would like to know, whether I can **explain the variability of grooming** events `[grooming]`  with these 5 characteristics of males `[m_char]` (x1, x2,...x5).

[image]

My approach was to perform CCA (a.k.a. canonical correspondence analysis) as following:

```
library(vegan)
my.cca <- cca(grooming ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
              data = m_char,
              scale = TRUE)
```

and test this model by anova to obtain p-values for factors

```
anova(my.cca, by="terms", permutations=1000)

# Permutation test for cca under reduced model
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# Permutation: free
# Number of permutations: 1000
# 
# Model: cca(formula = grooming ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
#            data = m_char, scale = TRUE)
#          Df ChiSquare      F   Pr(>F)   
# x1        1    0.5327 1.1054 0.718282   
# x2        1    0.6216 1.2899 0.359640   
# x3        1    0.6341 1.3159 0.314685   
# x4        1    0.6739 1.3984 0.191808   
# x5        1    0.8782 1.8225 0.008991 **
# Residual 10    4.8188                   
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Although, x5 seems to have significant effect on grooming, when I look on plot...

```
plot(my.cca)
```

...apes from one cage seems to **strongly group together**.

I think that the structure of my data causes a problem to cca analysis, because, when you look on table with numbers of interactions...

[image]

...only zeros in yellow squares are **"true"** zeros (i.e. there is **no** interactions between apes), **the rest of zeros outside yellow squares are just a consequence of being in different cage**.

> Is it possible to somehow tell the CCA to **ignore "false zeros"?** How to
>   incorporate such data structure appropriately? My main aim is to find
>   whether one or multiple characteristics of males can be used to
>   explain the grooming rates.

***Thank you very much for any suggestion!***

---

**"grooming" example data:**

```
AF1 <- c(3,7,2,0,rep(0, times = 12))
AF2 <- c(8,0,0,3,rep(0, times = 12))
AF3 <- c(0,2,0,0,rep(0, times = 12))
AF4 <- c(4,0,1,0,rep(0, times = 12))
AF4 <- c(4,0,1,0,rep(0, times = 12))
BF1 <- c(rep(0, times = 4),4,1,5,0,rep(0, times = 8))
BF2 <- c(rep(0, times = 4),3,0,0,1,rep(0, times = 8))
BF3 <- c(rep(0, times = 4),0,2,0,0,rep(0, times = 8))
BF4 <- c(rep(0, times = 4),0,0,7,0,rep(0, times = 8))
CF1 <- c(rep(0, times = 8),4,0,4,0,rep(0, times = 4))
CF2 <- c(rep(0, times = 8),2,0,0,0,rep(0, times = 4))
CF3 <- c(rep(0, times = 8),0,3,0,4,rep(0, times = 4))
CF4 <- c(rep(0, times = 8),0,0,9,0,rep(0, times = 4))
DF1 <- c(rep(0, times = 12),0,2,0,0)
DF2 <- c(rep(0, times = 12),6,0,0,1)
DF3 <- c(rep(0, times = 12),0,0,1,0)
DF4 <- c(rep(0, times = 12),4,0,1,0)

male_id <- c("AM1", "AM2", "AM3", "AM4",
             "BM1", "BM2", "BM3", "BM4",
             "CM1", "CM2", "CM3", "CM4",
             "DM1", "DM2", "DM3", "DM4")

grooming <- data.frame(AF1,AF2,AF3,AF4,
                       BF1,BF2,BF3,BF4,
                       CF1,CF2,CF3,CF4,
                       DF1,DF2,DF3,DF4)
rownames(grooming) <- male_id
```

**"m_char" example data:**

```
x1 <- c(2,5,3,1,8,1,1,6,2,3,5,1,1,6,6,7)
x2 <- c(4,9,1,3,2,1,9,4,3,1,9,2,9,1,4,3)
x3 <- c(1,2,5,4,4,4,5,2,2,1,1,1,2,5,5,9)
x4 <- c(4,1,1,8,8,6,6,6,6,8,1,6,2,2,1,1)
x5 <- c(1,7,3,3,4,1,5,1,3,8,4,8,8,5,9,9)

m_char <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
rownames(m_char) <- male_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the permutation test you are using is too liberal; it assumes a Null hypothesis in which all observations are exchangeable. From what you say, observations within a cage *are* exchangeable, but are not exchangeable *between* cages.

To use the more restrictive null in the permutation test we can use a restricted permutation design, in which we ask **vegan** to only permute observations within cages and never between cages. This is most easily done using a blocking factor.

Create the blocking factor:

```
m_char <- transform(m_char,
                    cage = factor(substring(rownames(m_char), 1, 1)))
```

Next, define the restricted permutation design (the defaults for `how()` mean we get randomisation *within* the levels of the factor passed to `blocks`)

```
ctrl <- how(nperm = 1000, blocks = m_char$cage)
```

Now fit the model and remove the between-cage variation, which is also required for these analyses with blocks

```
my.cca <- cca(grooming ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + Condition(cage),
              data = m_char)
```

Now do the restricted permutation test

```
set.seed(10)
anova(my.cca, by = "terms", permutations = ctrl)
```

This produces:

```
> anova(my.cca, by = "terms", permutations = ctrl)
Permutation test for cca under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Blocks:  m_char$cage 
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 1000

Model: cca(formula = grooming ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + Condition(cage), data = m_char)
         Df ChiSquare      F  Pr(>F)  
x1        1   0.52470 1.4119 0.15185  
x2        1   0.60901 1.6388 0.03397 *
x3        1   0.21703 0.5840 0.96503  
x4        1   0.36739 0.9886 0.36563  
x5        1   0.83984 2.2600 0.03497 *
Residual  7   2.60129                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And the triplot shows different behaviour to that you obtained

[image]

Does this make sense now?